# Deque class insert and removing front and rear not working interchangably [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, nodes, doubly-linked-list, deque

for my assignment I'm supposed to make a deque class that lets people insert from the front and the back, and also be able to remove from both the front and back, those are 4 separate functions in the Deque class.

If I use insert_front, then I can remove everything from the queue using remove_front, but if I use insert_front and try to use remove_rear, then my program breaks after doing remove_rear one time, it will remove the rear, but if I try to remove the next rear, the program breaks because there it doesn't know what the next rear node is, I have no idea how to be able to track both the front and rear so I can use these functions interchangeably. This also happens vice versa, with insert_rear and remove_front.

my code for the Deque class is as follows:

```
def insert_front( self, value ):


    if self._rear==None and len(self)==1:

        node = _DequeNode(value, self._front,self._rear)
        self._front = node
        self._rear=node
    else:
        node = _DequeNode(value, self._front,self._rear)
        self._front = node


    self._size += 1
    return

def insert_rear( self, value ):
    node = _DequeNode(value, self._front,self._rear)
    self._rear = node
    if self._front==None and len(self)==2:
        self._front=node


    self._size += 1
    return

def remove_front( self ):

    if self.is_empty():
        value = None
    else:
        current = self._front
        value = current._value
        self._front = current._next
        self._size -= 1

    return value

def remove_rear( self ):

    if self.is_empty():
        value = None
    else:
        current = self._rear
        value = current._value
        self._rear = current._prev
        self._size -= 1

    return value
```

and this is my _DequeNode class:

```
def __init__(self, value, next_node,prev_node):
    self._value = copy.deepcopy(value)
    self._next = next_node
    self._prev = prev_node
    return
```

I definitely did something wrong while altering the code, because this was originally for a linked list, where you can only remove and insert from the front, and the teacher asked us to make it into a Deque that has both front and rear, I edited the code based on what I thought was supposed to happen..

Can someone please help me with this? I've been trying to figure this out for the entire day!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Next time please provide the full class code and sample problematic output - it makes it easier to tell where your mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version I wrote up real quick.

Also I added a `__repr__` method so you could see what's happening (this isn't actually a good practice for a `__repr__` unless you also modify the `__init__` to be capable of taking the output as an argument.

You may also want to take a look at https://github.com/python-mirror/python/blob/master/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c - which contains the python `deque` implementation.

```
class DQ: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self._front = self._rear = None
        self._size = 0

    def insert_front( self, value ):
        self._front = DequeNode(value, prev=self.front)
        if self.size > 0:
            self.front.prev._next = self._front
        else: 
            self._rear = self._front
        self._size += 1

    def insert_rear( self, value ):
        self._rear = DequeNode(value, next=self.rear)
        if self.size > 0:
            self.rear.next._prev = self._rear
        else:
            self._front = self._rear
        self._size += 1

    def pop_front( self ):
        if self.empty:
            raise IndexError("deque is empty")
        else:
            ret = self._front
            self._size -= 1
            self._front = self._front.prev
            if self.front:
                self.front._next = None
            if self.size == 0: 
                self._front = None
            return ret

    def pop_rear( self ):
        if self.empty:
            raise IndexError("deque is empty")
        else:
            ret = self._rear
            self._size -= 1
            self._rear = self._rear.next
            if self.rear: 
                self.rear._prev = None
            if self.size == 0: 
                self._front = None
            return ret

    @property
    def empty(self): 
        return self._size == 0 
    @property
    def size(self): 
        return self._size
    @property
    def front(self): 
        return self._front
    @property
    def rear(self):
        return self._rear

    def __str__(self): 
        cur = self.rear
        l = []
        for i in range(self.size): 
            l.append(cur)
            cur = cur.next
        return str(l)

    def __repr__(self): 
        return self.__str__()



class DequeNode: 
    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None, prev=None):
        self._value = value
        self._next =next
        self._prev = prev

    @property
    def prev(self):
        return self._prev
    @property
    def next(self):
        return self._next

    def __str__(self): 
        return str(self._value)

    def __repr__(self): 
        return str("DequeNode( %s )" %self._value)
```